Evaluate command inside comparison in makefile
I would like to check if Linux system is ubuntu inside Makefile. What I do is:
copy_files:
    if [ "$(head -n 1 /etc/lsb-release | cut -d '=' -f2)" = "Ubuntu" ]; then \
        echo "ubuntu"; \
    else \
        echo "not ubuntu"; \
    fi

But the above condition fails always, i.e. it always prints "not ubuntu" on an ubuntu machine. So What am I doing wrong?

Please [edit] your question and explain what "does not work" mean. Is there an error message? Does the test run but return the wrong value? Does it not run? Does it crash the build process?

Thanks. I just did so.

Related: Makefile command substitution

Related or a bona fide dupe, @steeldriver? Looks like the OP just needs to use $$(head -n 1 ...) for the reasons explained in that answer, right?

@terdon yes I think that's it - but there may be something I'm missing

Oh yes, using double $$ fixed it! Thanks very much!
